# Customize screen in ZXING scanner for android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, zxing

I am working on android zxing project , In that I need to add zxing scanner in tabbar (Host controller) I tried to resize zxing view but not succeeded, also I tried to set tabbar on zxing camera capture view but it also not working, 
Please any one can help?

Comment: Without any code and a better explanation, you'll only get downvotes and no answers.

Comment: is it compulsory for your project to use Zxing?

Comment: Have you been able to customise the UI?

Comment: @Deep Yes, I was able to customize UI.

Comment: @JayeshSojitra Great .... this is my thread... could you please help me out ... thanks ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355779/get-access-to-zxing-qr-scanner-camera-view/29356425?noredirect=1#comment46898985_29356425