# Get access to Zxing QR scanner camera view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-camera, zxing

I am new to android development and I am working on an android project where I have to integrate QR scanner. So I thought I would integrate Zxing QR scanner and came across this library https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner, Following the instructions provided I have successfully integrated and scanned a QR as well.
Now I want to customise the camera view. The problem is there is no documentation on how to get access to the camera layout. Since I am new I might be missing something.

I have read through many Zxing related threads but I din find any solution.

Any help will be greatly appreciated either by letting me know on how I can get access to the camera view or pointing me out to some articles. Once I know how then I can complete the rest.

I would be happy to provide any further information.

Thanks in advance.

Update:

```
public class QrScanActivity extends BaseActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_scan);

        // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        // Set the scanner view as the content view
        setContentView(mScannerView);
    }
```

`mScannerView` is the view from the library. I want to get access to that view. I have a view called as `activity_my_scan`. I can add custom layout to that and use that but I don't know how to bypass the layout being used by the library.

Comment: Actually there are many tutorials about this out there like this for instance ;) : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_camera.htm

Comment: @AndroidProgrammer Great thanks. The article helps in understanding how to customise the UI. But the problem is I am unable to get access to my custom XML layout. I have updated my question. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just adding this lib as a jar using gradle's

```
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.6.3'
```

you could clone the project from github or download a zip and uzip it and integrate to your project as a lib project. And then make any desired changes in its sources and its layouts.

Comment: Nope. I downloaded the project. But the same problem. M just unable to figure out how to get hold of the camera view used in the project. Even if I can replace it it would be great. But I don't know how.

Comment: Examine the source code, find the view it uses at scanning time, I guess there will be some layout. And don't forget to remove `compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.6.3'` from your biuld.

Comment: You are right there is an xml, m unable to edit it. If I edit, while build it disappears. I tried downloading and then integrating it but there are lot of dependencies and I am missing few. Unable to figure out which ones I am missing. The download is giving me zxing and zbar and few samples.

Comment: Yes, usually it does contain a project by itself and samples. You should integrate to your app only the project by itself without any samples. Point  AS to the folder with library source project instead of the root folder with sources and samples and other stuff to add only the source code and its resources. You should add folders `core`, `zxing` and `zbar` previously deleting the `sample` folders from last two.

Comment: Actually I bleive that you could add (using AS import) only the `core` folder and then add `zbar` and `zxing` modules using gradle.

Answer (score 0):

ZXingScannerView extends BarcodeScannerView. You can access this by going to the declaration of ZXingScannerView (in Android Studio Ctrl+B).

```
public class ZXingScannerView extends BarcodeScannerView {
private MultiFormatReader mMultiFormatReader;
public static final List<BarcodeFormat> ALL_FORMATS = new ArrayList();
private List<BarcodeFormat> mFormats;
private ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler mResultHandler;
```

If you go the declaration of BarcodeScannerView, you'll notice a method called setupLayout() which formats the layout:

```
public void setupLayout() {
    this.mPreview = new CameraPreview(this.getContext());
    this.mViewFinderView = new ViewFinderView(this.getContext());
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this.getContext());
    relativeLayout.setGravity(17);
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(-16777216);
    relativeLayout.addView(this.mPreview);
    this.addView(relativeLayout);
    this.addView(this.mViewFinderView);
}
```

By going to the declaration of "CameraPreview" you'll be able to get more info for how the camera is laid out and you could maybe extend ZXingScannerView to edit the layout.

Hope this helps!

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Well in your case i would try to include the layout into another layout, maybe it helps:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”match_parent”
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width=”match_parent”
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/hello"
              android:padding="10dp" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

And of course there is information about that [here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include) ;)

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I am looking for. I will try Stans method and see if it works.